# The router blocks my computer at a certain hour

Tags: wireless-networking

My dad recently made changes to the wifi settings and started blocking only my computer at a certain hour.

I would like to understand a little bit more about what is going on and how the settings work.

Is there any way to get around this setting?

Comment: What router do you have?

Comment: Your father probably wants you to go to bed at a decent hour, have you thought to just talk to him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most router have an option to block computers using certain rules, usually based on the MAC address of the network card. Now you could go out and buy a new wifi adapter (which has a new MAC address) but this would also show up in the list of computers that are connecting making it easy to add this MAC as well. Now you would have to go out and buy a yet another network card.

Another way is to [spoof your MAC](http://www.howtogeek.com/192173/how-and-why-to-change-your-mac-address-on-windows-linux-and-mac/), this way you can change is to something new every day without having to buy a new network card.

For windows computers go to Device manager and select properties on the network card you are using. On the tab "Advanced" select "Network address" and type in a random MAC address. Note that this will only work if your network card supports this, else this option will not be visible.

On the other hand, if your dad knows a bit about network control, he could easy limit the users which can connect to the network to only certain MAC addresses, leaving you with no option to connect with a made-up MAC. In this case you would have to spoof a MAC that is known, e.g. his computer or phone MAC.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Ramhound - added a brief description

Comment: thanks that helps a lot. I know he does limit the access to only certain addresses so i guess i will have to spoof some other address.

Answer (score 2):

Many routers have features like this.  The exact method of configuration would depend on the router.  Here's a screenshot from AirPort Utility for configuring an Apple AirPort Extreme, for example.  It limits "Your PC" wireless access between 9 AM and 9 PM.  This screen is accessible from AirPort Utility->Network->Timed Access Control.

[image]